# Android: Searchview searches only whole words

Tags: android, searchview

Search is based on starting characters, but i would like that will search everything.
Here is part of my code, method onTextChanged isn't right, I think.. Thanks for help!

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final ArrayList<String> seznamPojmov = (ArrayList<String>) SeznamPojmovRazlag(0); 
    final ArrayList<String> array_sort= new ArrayList<String>();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_slovar);

    final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.slovar);
    final EditText iskanje = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.iskanje);

    final ArrayAdapter a = new ArrayAdapter<String (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, seznamPojmov);
    list.setAdapter(a);
    iskanje.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.}
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,int start, int count, int after)
        {
            // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
        }
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,int start, int before, int count)
        {
            int len=0;
            len = iskanje.getText().length();
            array_sort.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < seznamPojmov.size(); i++)
            {
                if (len <= seznamPojmov.get(i).length())
                {
            if(iskanje.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String)seznamPojmov.get(i).subSequence(0,len)))
                    {
                        array_sort.add(seznamPojmov.get(i));
                        }
                    }
                }
            list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> (Slovar.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_sort));
            }
    });
```

Comment: exactly when you want to search..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use contains() method as like this

replace

```
 if(iskanje.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String)seznamPojmov.get(i).subSequence(0,len)))
```

with

```
 if((boolean)seznamPojmov.get(i).contains(iskanje.getText().toString()))
```

Comment: I did stupid mistake.. I replaced with:

if((boolean)seznamPojmov.get(i).contains(iskanje.getText().toString())
now it works :) thank you!

Comment: You can also use this `if(seznamPojmov.get(i).contains(iskanje.getText().toString()))`